# Prevent Component Flicker in React State Update

Tags: reactjs

I load data for a table in a two-step process. The first load gets the basic info for the table. The second load goes row by row with more data-intensive queries. When the query returns, we update the row's info, then call `setItems([...data])` to rerender the table with the updated data from the row.

The problem is that this causes a flicker when hovering a link in the row, as the entire table is re-rendered every second or so as the next row's data comes in.

Here is the relevant code from my useData hook:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState<T[]>([] as T[])

const data = await fetchPrimaryData()
setItems(data)

for (const item of data) {
  await secondaryRequest(item) // secondary request mutates item
  setItems([...data])
}
```

If you remove the second `setItems`, the data gets updated, but the state is not updated until you start clicking around and causing a refresh some other way.

My preference would be to just re-render the row which has been updated, but since the table relies on a `data: T[]` prop, anytime part of the data changes, the whole table re-renders and causes the flicker.

Comment: I don't think anyone can give a tested solution when we don't know anything about the table itself. But, could you make a row component that was responsible for the secondary request? That way only the single row would refresh when the data comes back. Although, I am suspicious this is your only problem react is usually pretty good at only refreshing the parts that need to be.

Comment: One possibility is do you have a key for each row? If not react has trouble knowing what changed and didn't.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution could be, useCallback hook. It will solve your problem of unnecessary re-rendering. i.e.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState<T[]>([] as T[])


const loadPrimaryData = useCallback(async () => {
 const data = await fetchPrimaryData();
 setItems(data);
}, []);

const loadSecondaryData = useCallback(async () => {
 for (const item of data) {
  await secondaryRequest(item)
  setItems([...data])
}}, [data]);
```

Further, if you want to load data one after another, depending on your use-case, you can use useEffect hook.